# Unable to Access provisioning profile in developer.apple.com

Tags: certificate, ios-provisioning

I have been working in an organization and recently purchased membership developer account and I was invited to join it and I joined.

As I started creating certificate using CodeSigningRequest it created a new certificate.
But when I am trying to add a new app-id it says

> An unexpected error occurred

And when I am trying to create a new provisioning profile it says

> Access Unavailable
>   Your membership privileges do not include access to this page.
>   To view your current membership status and benefits, click View Account.

Please let me know whether I need to be admin to create provisioning profiles or an appid

Comment: even i used safari also same issue. Do i need admin access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to log in to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), the **Users and Roles**, select a user (yourself) and get *Team Admin* role.

See [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html):

**Agent** (there can be only one)

> Only a team agent can create a Developer ID certificate. If you have a company membership, read Managing Your Team in Member Center for a description of team roles and tasks that team agents perform on behalf of team members.

**Admin** (manage certificates, make other admins, etc.)

> A team admin can set the privilege levels of other team members, except the team agent. Team admins manage all assets used to sign your apps, either during development or when your team is ready to distribute an app. Team admins are the only people on a team who can sign apps for distribution on nondevelopment devices. Team admins also approve signing certificate requests made by team members.

See [Managing Your Team in Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW1):
(Contact any Agent or Admin to become an Admin)

> A team agent is legally responsible for the team and acts as the primary contact with Apple. The team agent can invite team members and change the access level of any other team member. There’s only one team agent.

If you do not see the *Users and Roles* as below in *iTunes Connect*, you are neither Agent nor Admin.

[image: iTunes Admin page]

Comment: Under iTunes Connect i logged in and i clicked "Apps" and then it asked me to "Get Started" and i clicked get started it is showing me the option to Enroll?

Comment: So you mean i don't have permission. I may be a team member not admin, So i need admin rights?